# MySQL Count single row based on 3 different criteria

Tags: mysql, optimization

I want to return an associative array based on a mySQL query such that the query results in 3 columns which are a count of a single set of data in 3 different ways. My best solution is a bit unweildly and I'm hoping there's a better way as there are some irrelevant complexities not shown below. Specifically I have a user table with a user number, their gender, and a place - the place being the dynamic variable which needs to be bound into the query later (in this instance I'm looking for place = 1). The basic table looks like this:

```
user gender  place
1      m       1
2      m       2
3      f       1
4      m       1
5      f       2
```

I'd like to return 3 columns which are total, total male, total female at place 1.

My first attempt returns 3 rows with the right values, but as they are rows I can't access them cleanly using an associative array:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user) as total FROM users WHERE place=1
UNION ALL 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_customer) as male FROM users
    WHERE gender = 'm' AND place=1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_customer) as female FROM users
    WHERE gender = 'f' AND place=1
```

My second attempt gives me the correct result but seems a bit verbose as I'll have to bind the place variable 3 times - is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT total, male, female FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user) as total FROM users
        WHERE place=1
        ) as total
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user) as male  FROM users
        WHERE place=1 AND gender='m') as male
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user) as female  FROM users
        WHERE place=1 AND gender='f') as female
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the DISTINCT part? or is "user" field unique (primary key or otherwise)?

I prepared both versions in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/928fa/7

If user is unique, then this should be enough:

```
SELECT count(1), sum(gender='m'), sum(gender='f')
FROM users
WHERE place=1;
```

Comment: Ah yes - so simple! Thanks for that. Yep, I need my DISTINCT in the actual application, but its not relevant to this question as you pointed out